# Members of a nested namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

Assuming `namespace A2` is nested within `namespace A1`, then `A2` is a member of enclosing  `A1`. But members of `A2` ( thus types declared within `A2` ) are not  members of `A1`.

a) What exactly is meant by members of `A2` not being members of `A1`? In other words, what would be different if they were also members of `A1`? Perhaps that inside `A1` we wouldn’t have to use fully qualified name for types in defined in `A2`?

b) What exactly is it meant by namespace `A2` being a member of `A1`?

BTW - I do understand namespaces, I'm just confused by the terminology used by my book ( namely,  A2 being a **member** of A1 etc )

thanx

**EDIT**

1) So essentially `A2` being a member of `A1` is the reason why inside `A1` we don't have to specify `A1. prefix` when referencing types declared in `A2`:

```
namespace A1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A2.classA2 a2= A2.classA2(); //here we don't need to include A1.
                                           prefix
        }
    }

    namespace A2
    {
       class classA2 { }
    }
}
```

2) The following is defined within `assembly asmLibrary.dll`

```
namespace A
{
    public class A1{}


    namespace B
    {
        public class B1{}
    }
}
```

The following application `App1` also has a reference to assembly `asmLibrary.dll`:

```
namespace A
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B.B1 instanceB1 = new B.B1();
        }
    }
}
```

The following application `App2` has a reference to assembly `asmLibrary.dll`:

```
using A;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A.B.B1 bInstance = new A.B.B1(); 

            A1 a1 = new A1();
        }
    }
}
```

a) When we tried  to declare in `App2` an instance of `A.B.B1`, we needed to specify fully qualified name of the type. But with `App1` we were allowed to specify the type via `B.B1`. Thus why were we allowed to ommit the `A.` prefix inside `App1`, but not inside `App2` ( `App2` has a `using A;` directive, so its behaviour should be identical to that of `App1` )?

b) Also, if `namespace B` is a member of `namespace A`, shouldn't then `App2` allow us to declare a type `A.B.B1` using  `B.B1 instanceB1 = new B.B1();` syntax?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following

```
namespace A1
{
    namespace A2  // A1.A2
    {
        class C2  // full name: A1.A2.C2
        {
            private A1.C1 c1b;   // full name 
            private C1 c1b;      // shortest form. A1 is in scope here
        }
    }

    class C1   // full name: A1.C1
    {
        private A1.A2.C2 c2a;   // full name
        private A2.C2 c2b;      // shortest form. We can omit the A1 prefix but not A2
    }
}
```

Answers

a) the class C2 is not a (direct) member of A1, so outside of the A2 namespace we have to declare
it as `A2.C2 c2b;`

b) The members of A1 are in scope inside A2, see the declaration of `C1 c1b;`

---

Re the Edit:

Your example shows the different effects of  `using a; ...` and `namespace A { ... }`.

The using statements 'imports the ***types*** from A [(§ 16.3.2)](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/16.3.2.htm#using-namespace-directive)' while in App2 the code *is* inside the namespace.
The term 'member' can be a bit confusing here.

Comment: So esentially saying A2 is a member of A1 simply means that inside A1 we don't have to specify A1. prefix when referencing types declared in A2?

Comment: Here's some extra thoughts:

 1. Namespaces are used to organize your classes in logical collections. To further organize things you can 'nest' namespaces: `My.Namespace` and `My.Namespace.Nested`. However this has no impact on a given type at runtime. At runtime the namespace is just a string that may or may not have a `.` in it.

 2. What namespaces do affect is type name resolution during compilation, which is based on (in simplification) the namespace of the current type and the `using` statements in your file. Henk's example illustrates this quite well.

Comment: @flockofcode: Yes. A2 and C1 are both members of A1 and much of the same rules apply.

Comment: »@flockofcode: Yes. A2 and C1 are both members of A1 and much of the same rules apply.«
But according to my book A2 is a member of A1, while C1 is not a member of A1

Comment: As fara s i understand, if C1 was a also member of A1, then we would be able to also reference C1 via A1.C1 and not just via A1.A2.C1

Comment: @flockofcode, I think you should read it again (-:  A1.C1 is correct.

Comment: Ups, I thought C1 was declared within A2. Anyways, if you read the edit I made in my original post, you'll notice that namespaces App2 display some different behaviour than namespaces in your example and App1. Any idea why that is?

Comment: According to the link you've provided using directive imports types contained in A, but it doesn't import namespaces nested in A. Anyways, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Members of A2 are members of A2 - "the buck stops there".  If the A1 contained definitions of the members of A2 then nothing changes - whichever way you'll need to reference these members as A1.member and members of A2 as A1.A2.member - unless you have `using` statements in which case you'll need to tread carefully if you want to avoid compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

- What exactly is it meant by namespace A2 being a member of A1?

The meaning of member is covered in the C# specification, section 3.4:

> **Members**
>
> Namespaces and types have members. The members of an entity are generally available through the use of a qualified name that starts with a reference to the entity, followed by a “.” token, followed by the name of the member.
>
> Members of a type are either declared in the type declaration or inherited from the base class of the type. [...]

The definition of "namespace members" is given section 3.4.1:

> **Namespace members**
>
> [...]
>
> Namespaces and types declared within a namespace are members of that namespace.

- What exactly is meant by members of A2 not being members of A1?

It means that just because `A1.A2.Foo` works, it doesn't imply that `A1.Foo` also works.

Comment: Would you be willing to help me a bit more? Namely I've edited my original post

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, IL has no concept of namespaces. The compiler appends namespace names and type names to compose longer full names; for example, class `Customer` in namespace `MyCompany.MyProduct` will be rendered as something like `MyCompany$MyProduct$Customer` when compiled into IL. To the IL virtual machine, that is a type name; the fact that it contains `$` signs is irrelevant.

From that fact you can derive your own conclusions. :-)